# How to randomly generate scratch like lines with opencv automatically

Tags: python, opencv, data-augmentation

I am trying to generate synthetic images for my deep learning model. I need to draw scratches on a black surface. I already have a little script that can generate random white scratch like lines but only horizontally. I need the scratches to also be vertically and curved. On top of that it would also be very helpfull if the thickness of the scratches would also be random so I have thick and thin scratches.

This is my code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

height = 384
width = 384
blank_image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

num_scratches= random.randint(0,5)
for _ in range(num_scratches):
    row_random = random.randint(20,370)
    blank_image[row_random:(row_random+1), row_random:(row_random+random.randint(25,75))] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow("synthetic", blank_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is one example result outcome:

[image]

How do I have to edit my script so I can get more diverse looking scratches?

The scratches should somehow look like this for example (Done with paint):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieve by generating the 3 control points of a bezier curve.

```py
from collections.abc import Generator

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def bezier(p1: np.ndarray, p2: np.ndarray, p3: np.ndarray) -> Generator[np.ndarray, None, None]:
    def calc(t):
        return t * t * p1 + 2 * t * (1 - t) * p2 + (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p3

    # get the approximate pixel count of the curve
    approx = cv.arcLength(np.array([calc(t)[:2] for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 10)], dtype=np.float32), False)
    for t in np.linspace(0, 1, round(approx * 1.2)):
        yield np.round(calc(t)).astype(np.int32)


def generate_scratch(img: np.ndarray, max_length: float, end_brush_range: tuple[float, float], mid_brush_range: tuple[float, float]) -> np.ndarray:
    H, W = img.shape
    # generate the 2 end points of the bezier curve
    x, y, rho1, theta1 = np.random.uniform([0] * 4, [W, H, max_length, np.pi * 2])
    p1 = np.array([x, y, 0])
    p3 = p1 + [rho1 * np.cos(theta1), rho1 * np.sin(theta1), 0]

    # generate the second point, make sure that it cannot be too far away from the middle point of the 2 end points
    rho2, theta2 = np.random.uniform([0], [rho1 / 2, np.pi * 2])
    p2 = (p1 + p3) / 2 + [rho2 * np.cos(theta2), rho2 * np.sin(theta2), 0]

    # generate the brush sizes of the 3 points
    p1[2], p2[2], p3[2] = np.random.uniform(*np.transpose([end_brush_range, mid_brush_range, end_brush_range]))

    for x, y, brush in bezier(p1, p2, p3):
        cv.circle(img, (x, y), brush, 255, -1)
    return img


if __name__ == "__main__":
    W, H = 640, 480

    MAX_LENGTH = 100  # maximum distance between two end points
    END_BRUSH_RANGE = (0, 1)  # brush size range of the two end points
    MID_BRUSH_RANGE = (2, 5)  # brush size range of the mid point
    SCRATCH_CNT = 30

    img = np.zeros((H, W), np.uint8)
    for _ in range(SCRATCH_CNT):
        generate_scratch(img, MAX_LENGTH, END_BRUSH_RANGE, MID_BRUSH_RANGE)

    cv.imshow("img", img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

Output image:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

*need the scratches to also be vertically*

Your method might be adopted as follows

```
import numpy as np  # cv2 read image into np.array
img = np.zeros((5,5),dtype='uint8')  # same as loading 5 x 5 px black rectangle
img[1:4,2:3] = 255
print(img)
```

Output:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Explanation: I set all elements (pixel) which have y-cordinate between 1 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive) and x-cordinate between 2 (inclusive) and 3 (exclusive).
Nonetheless `cv2` provide function for drawing lines namely [cv2.line](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html#drawing-line) which is more handy to use, it does accept `img` on which to work, start point, end point, color and thickness, docs give following example:

```
# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
```

If you are working in grayscale use value rather than 3-tuple as color.